# local constexpr variable introduces compiler error

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, constexpr

The following code compiles and works as expected unless you swap the line marked *ok* for the line marked *fails*. The only difference is that I'm making a local temporary constexpr variable. I don't understand why it fails in one case only.

```
#include <array>

using TArray = std::array<int, 2>;
using TSize  = TArray::size_type;

constexpr TSize Fn(const TArray& myArray) 
{
    //constexpr TSize ret{myArray.size()}; return ret; // fails
    return myArray.size();                           // ok
}

int main()
{
    constexpr TArray ar{};
    constexpr TSize i{Fn(ar)};
    return i;
}
```

The error I get with gcc and c++17 is

```
<source>: In function 'constexpr TSize Fn(const TArray&)':
<source>:15:39: error: 'myArray' is not a constant expression
   15 |     constexpr TSize ret{myArray.size()}; return ret; // fails
```

I'd like to add that I realise the error states myArray is not a constant expression.  I can't make it a constant expression because it is a reference parameter.
My question is **not** how I can fix the code or get it working.  It's why does the compiler accept the *ok* like but not *fail* line?

Comment: I think you should tag this with [language-lawyer] and remove [gcc].

Comment: a `constexpr` function must be a legal function, which means it can be called not in a constant expression, and in this case its arguments may not be a constant expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour occurs because

- The expression `myArray.size()` that appears inside the function is not a constant expression *per se*, because it accesses a reference variable whose initialization is not visible within the context of this expression.
- The expression `Fn(ar)` *is* a constant expression despite the fact that its evaluation involves the evaluation of `myArray.size()` inside the function call. When `myArray.size()` is evaluated *as part of* `Fn(ar)`, the initialization of the reference parameter is visible (the function call itself performs that initialization).
- When you declare a variable `constexpr`, the compiler determines whether the initialization of said variable is a valid constant expression *per se*;
- Therefore, `Fn(ar)` may be used to initialize a `constexpr` variable, but `myArray.size()` may not.

It may be surprising that a constant expression is sometimes allowed to contain expressions that are not constant expressions *per se*.

Comment: I thought `myArray.size()` is a `constexpr`. Could you explain what you mean by it is not *per se*?

Comment: @Ant as you already observed in your post, it's not a constant expression because `myArray` is a reference parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You will see, that the compiler accepts the fails line, if you remove the `constexpr`. A variable that is `constexpr` must be initialized at compile time (that also means it is implicitly static). But a function that is marked `constexpr` potentially *can* be called at compile time, but it does not have to. It can also be called at runtime and then, this initialization would not be at compile time but at runtime. And that is forbidden. For `constexpr` functions you should always think about if they would also work, if you remove the `constexpr`.